# Electron TypeError: $(...).jstree is not a function when i try to use it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

i'm using `jstree` i have downloaded code from here https://www.jstree.com/

found `jstree.js` from `dist folder` and put into my `/js/jstree.js`

**imported jstree like this:**

```
if(inElectron()){
    window.jQuery = require('./js/jquery.min.js');
    window.$ = window.jQuery;
    window.jstree = require('./js/jstree.js');
}
```

**when i try to use it:**

`$('#jstree').jstree();// for just demo with minimal code`  (Actually i'm using full code from here http://jsfiddle.net/t4s7dz52/)

i'm getting below error:

> "TypeError: $(...).jstree is not a function

**Note:** i'm able to use `jQuery` throughout project ,so no `import error` as both `js` are in same folder

Please help me thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Did you try importing jQuery first?

Comment: jstree depends on jQuery. Can't load jQuery plugins before you load the library itself

Comment: @DaveNewton,@ charlietfl, sorry during code reformatting `jstree` moved up, even now i'm getting same **ERROR** , **UPDATED code here**

Comment: @skBangalore did the approach I suggested work for you?

Comment: @skBangalore, are you sure jsTree has actually been imported? Because the error "$(...).jstree is not a function" suggests the otherwise. Try adding `console.log( typeof window.jQuery.fn.jstree );` right after the `require()` line for jsTree, and see what the console says.

Answer (score 0):

The jstree module exports a factory which has to be invoked first, so that jstree can register as jQuery plugin. Try the following:

```
window.jQuery = require('./js/jquery.min.js');
window.$ = window.jQuery;
window.jstree = require('./js/jstree.js')(window.$);
```

Answer (score 0):

If using electron:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./path/to/jquery');</script>
```

Comment: Which is exactly what he did in the first two lines he posted?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
//wrapped to load after jQuery
$(function(){
    ....
    window.jstree = require('./js/jstree.js');
    $('#jstree').jstree();
    ....

});
```

Comment: @skBangalore I've updated answer, as another version.